# Model scope works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm was surprised to see a scope that works locally isn't responding correctly on heroku. Does heroku define a scope once and not again? Is there a better way to write these scopes?

```
# Offset date for early morning hours
if Time.now.hour < 4
  scope :upcoming, lambda { between(Date.tomorrow, Date.tomorrow+4.days) }
  scope :tomorrow, lambda { on(Date.today) }
  scope :today, lambda { on(Date.yesterday).not_over }
else
  scope :upcoming, lambda { between(Date.tomorrow+1.day, Date.tomorrow+5.days) }
  scope :tomorrow, lambda { on(Date.tomorrow) }
  scope :today, lambda { on(Date.today).not_over }
end
```

It checks if the time is between 12am and 4am. If it is, it defines `:today`, `:tomorrow`, and `:upcoming` as starting from yesterday. If not, it defines the scopes normally.

This is so when a user is looking for an upcoming event that's "today" and it's 1am in the morning on a Friday night, s/he'll see events that are still going on until 4am. For instance, a club that hasn't closed yet.

Heroku is defining my scopes by the else statement regardless of what time it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for you locally because your local webserver **reloads all classes** every time you refresh a page. In production (heroku env) this obviously will not happen for performance reasons. Classes are loaded just once, at app startup. So whatever time was at that moment, it will define which set of scopes is created.

I suggest rewriting your scopes like this (move time check into scopes themselves):

```
scope :upcoming, lambda { 
  diff = Time.now.hour < 4 ? 0 : 1
  between(Date.tomorrow+diff.day, Date.tomorrow+(4 + diff).days) 
}
```